Cannot map the input column, 'Date', to the lookup column, 'Date', because the data types do not match
I'm getting this error:

TITLE: Microsoft Visual Studio
Cannot map the input column, 'Date', to the lookup column, 'Date', because the data types do not match.

Data type in SSMS
Changed type to date, tried few different date type
Still not able to map date to date

As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

you should convert your date column in source table to YYYYMMDD format by using the statement below:
SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(10),YourDateColumn,112) AS Sample_Date_Format

Then do the matching between above converted column and DateKey Column on your lookup table, not Date Column:
